# Finding modulo inverse if gcd is not 1

Tags: math, modulo

I have to find (p^e-1)/(p-1) mod 1000000007, where p is a prime number.
if gcd(p-1,1000000007) is not 1, then the modular inverse of (p-1) is not defined. Also, (p^e-1) is divisible by (p-1) (sum of a Geometric Progression). Also I can't find (p^e-1) since p,e<=10^18. So how do I find (p^e-1)/(p-1) mod 1000000007

Comment: This might be better suited for Math.SE

Comment: You should ask this on [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead as your question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Actually I was solving a competitive programming question, and i came up with this formula. That's why I asked it here

Answer (score 2):

When you're dividing integers, and then taking the modulus, you have to treat the prime factors of the modulus in a special manner. Consider for example 6/3 mod 3. If we just tried to write 6/3 mod 3 = (6 mod 3)/(3 mod 3) we would have undefined 0/0, whereas the correct answer is of course 6/3 mod 3 = 2 mod 3 = 2.

So what we need to do is to factor powers of 3 out of both the numerator and denominator, and divide those separately (by subtracting exponents). So we have 6 = 3^1 x 2, 3 = 3^1 x 1, so 6/3 = 3^1/3^1 x 2/1 = 3^{1-1} x 2 = 3^0 x 2 = 2 mod 3. Let's try a more complicated example: 18/6 mod 3 = (3^2 x 2)/(3^1 x 2) = 3^{2-1} x 2/2 = 3 x 1 = 3 mod 3 = 0.

Here's another example: 36/18 = (3^2 x 4)/(3^2 x 2) = 3^{2-2} x 4 x 2^{-1} mod 3 = 4 x 2 mod 3 (since 2^{-1} = 2 mod 3) = 8 mod 3 = 2. In general, we subtract exponents of the power of 3 part, and invert mod 3 the non-power of 3 part of the divisor.

In your example, we have to find the highest power m of 1000000007 that goes into p^e-1, and rewrite p^e-1 = 1000000007^m x s, where s is relatively prime to 1000000007. We do the same for p-1 = 1000000007^n x t, where t is relatively prime to 1000000007. Then the quotient (p^e-1)/(p-1) = 1000000007^{m-n} x s x t^{-1}. The answer is 0 mod 1000000007 if m>n; otherwise the answer is s x t^{-1} mod 1000000007. The inverse of t mod 1000000007 exists because t is relatively prime to 1000000007; the inverse can be calculated by a modified version of the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Since 1000000007 is prime, there are two cases.

Case 1: 1000000007 is a factor of p-1. Then p mod 1000000007 = 1, so 1+p+p^2+...+p^(e-1) = 1+1+1...+1 = e mod 1000000007.

Case 2: 1000000007 is relatively prime to p-1 and you can compute 1/(p-1) as (p-1)^1000000005 mod 1000000007, or by using Euclid's algorithm, and you can compute powers mod 1000000007 relatively rapidly using exponentiation by squaring.

Answer (score 0):

[1000000007 is a prime number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%201000000007%20prime), so if `p-1 < 1000000007` the gcd will always be 1. If `p-1` is some multiple of 1000000007 then  by definition it is zero modulo 1000000007  and so there is no inverse defined .

Comment: That's not always true. gcd(11 - 1, 5) = 5. Both 11 and 5 are prime.

Comment: ok fair point i've added in the case where it's zero modulo 1000000007

Comment: it's a definition thing: inverse of x modolo y means the number that you can multiply x by so that i get 1 + (something times y). but if x = (something times y) than any multiple of x will also have the same form so you can never get what you need.

Comment: So that means 1/(p-1) mod 1000000007 isn't defined ??

Comment: yes, but this probably won't be the case, think how unlikely it is that p-1 will be a multiple of such a huge prime

Answer (score 0):

You have two cases

1. `p-1` is coprime to the large prime `1000000007`.  This is always true for `p <= 1000000007` and usually true for larger `p`.  It seems you know what to do in this case - use an algorithm to find the modular inverse of `p-1`, i.e. `a` such that `a * (p - 1) == 1 mod 1000000007`.
2. `p-1` is a multiple of `1000000007` - i.e. `p-1 == k*1000000007`.  In this case, `p == k*1000000007 + 1`

   Let us turn our attention to the top line of the expression

   ```
   p^e - 1 == (k * 1000000007 + 1) ^ e - 1
   ```

   This can be expanded by the binomial expansion as

   ```
   ((k*1000000007)^e + e*(k*1000000007)^(e-1) + ... + 1) - 1
   ```

   Remember, though, that `(k*1000000007) == p-1`. So, the expansion is

   ```
   ((p-1)^e + e*(p-1)^(e-1) + ... + e*(p-1))
   ```

   We can divide through this by `p-1` and are left with

   ```
   ((p-1)^(e-2) + e*(p-1)^(e-2) + .... + e)
   ```

   We know that all the terms containing `p-1` are 0 mod 1000000007 in this case, so we are simply left with the last term, `e`.  Thus, in this case, the result of the expression `(p^e - 1) / (p - 1) mod 1000000007` is `e` - you do not find the modular inverse of `p-1` because you can't, but neither do you need to.